# Drupal, Who (username) downloaded what?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

Ive been searching for this answer for almost a week now.

What is the easiest way for an admin to view which files an authenticated user has downloaded? To be more specific, I need the username of the user and the name of the downloaded file and then I can check my registrations for their specific email addresses and use it for lead generation.

Ive tried Google Analytics, but I can only see whats being downloaded and when, not by which username.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1- Make sure that your files are stored as `private files` NOT `public files`.

2- Use [hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7)() to dig inside the private file download process (you can do anything you want from there).

Hope this helps... Muhammad.